# Finding where dependant object is called

Tags: ms-access

I have deleted a column inside a table that is used to populate a form in my database. After removing it, and removing the box from the form itself on loading the form it asks for a parameter for the field.

I have already updated the record source hoping that it would resolve the issue but it has not.
Is there a way I can see whats calling the field? I have looked through the VB code and all record sources.

Comment: Check that the field is not used in a sort, this is always a gotcha. It could be a sort on the query or the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than iterate through the controls and examine the code, you can :

```
 Application.SaveAsText acForm, "MyForm", "z:\docs\form.txt"
```

You can then search the text for the relevant field.